# How to crop an attached image in android?

Tags: android

I want to crop an image  from attachment before displaying it in my activity.. i m really struggled in this...

Here is mycode  for cropping an image:

```
Intent bigimgintent = new Intent("com.android.camera.CropImage"); 

bigimgintent.setClassName("com.android.gallery", "com.android.camera.CropImage"); 
bigimgintent.putExtra("crop", "true"); 
bigimgintent.putExtra("scale",false); 
bigimgintent.putExtra("return-data", return_data);
bigimgintent.putExtra("outputX",  1024); 
bigimgintent.putExtra("outputY", 768); 
bigimgintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
bigimgintent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

if (circleCrop) { 
    bigimgintent.putExtra("circleCrop", true); 
}

startActivityForResult(bigimgintent,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 bigimgintent.putExtra("crop", "true"); 
bigimgintent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
bigimgintent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
bigimgintent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
bigimgintent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
bigimgintent.putExtra("scale",true); // make this as true
```